# Custom Task Process

Tags: tasks, designer-workflow

I am trying to create a custom task process using SharePoint Designer. Once the approver approves the task, the approver should be able to select a person/group that will be notified of this outcome.

I tried creating a task form field so that it is available in the task completion form. I am successful up to this point because the form recognizes this field. I am able to add it to the canvas of the task form.

However, when I try to use this field on the workflow, and I presume this is treated as a parameter, I cannot find it. Thus, I cannot use the parameter in an action to send the notification email.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a taskform field inside a custom task only makes it available inside this custom task, to get the value out to your main workflow do the following:

1. In the main workflow start the task editor by clicking TaskName in `Start Taskname process on ...`
2. In the customization section click `Change the behavior of a single task`
3. Down in the `When a Task Completes` add a `Set Variable` where you set some new task variable to `Current Task: FieldName`
4. Now you can go back to the main workflow which now has the value from the last task in the variable.

Comment: Thank you Per Jakobsen. I have just tested an it works! I am going to win a gold medal on Monday Morning!!